# How to show sort icon based on computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I want to show the corresponding sort icon based on computed value. For example if the column1 was clicked, either classRefcodeDown or classRefcodeUp is true. both computed properties call a sortClassRefcode method which values will be evaluated with the filterOptions.sort_by (refcode, column2,column3, so on...) and filterOptions.sort_type ('ASC' or 'DESC'). But does not work accordingly. Pls. check my code below
HTML:

```html
<div v-if="classRefcodeDown"> 
      <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
  </div>
  <div v-else-if="classRefcodeUp"> 
      <i class="fas fa-sort-up"></i>
  </div>
  <div v-else> <i class="fas fa-sort"></i> 
</div>
```

vuejs computed

```js
computed: {          
    classRefcodeUp: function(){
        return this.sortClassRefcode('refcode', 'ASC')
    },
    classRefcodeDown: function(){
        return this.sortClassRefcode('refcode', 'DESC')
    }
}
```

vuejs methods

```js
methods: {
  sortClassRefcode: function(field, type) {
      if(this.filterOptions.sort_by == field && this.filterOptions.sort_type == type){
          return true
      }
      return false
  }
}
```

When I run these the computed properties changed accordingly but the icon appears does not reflects based on computed values

devtools-computed

[image: devtools-computed]

unexpected-output-icon

[image: unexpected-output-icon]

Comment: I think the problem is that your computed properties have no reactive dependencies

Answer (score 3):

Your computed properties have no actual dependencies.  At the simplest level, the dependencies of a computed property are any direct accesses to a value in the data property, or to another computed property.

> [A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods)

Both of your computed properties call a method without accessing either type of value, therefore a change will never be identified.

If you want it to react to changes,  check `this.filterOptions.sortyBy` and `this.filterOptions.sort_type`  in the computed property.

---

There's still an easier way to handle this though.  Why not just use a single computed property to get the icon, and use that as the class description?

```
computed: {
    refCodeClass() {
        if (this.filterOptions.sort_by === 'refcode') {
            return this.filterOptions.sort_type === 'ASC' 
                ? 'fa-sort-up' 
                : 'fa-sort-down';
        }
        return 'fas-sort''
    }
}
```

```
<i class="fas" :class="refCodeClass"></i>
```